# Ayuda en ordenar arreglo de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo de objetos muy simple, algo como esto:

```
let profiles = [
  {
    'title': 'X',
    'url' : 'https://google.com',
    'description': 'Lorem'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Y',
    'description': 'Ipsum'
  }
];
```

Cada objeto tiene las propiedades `title` y `description`, pero tiene de manera opcional `url`.

Hago un `sort` al arreglo para ordenarlo en orden alfabético según el `title`.

```
profiles.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase();
});
```

Y al final inserto los datos del arreglo en el HTML con un `forEach`:

```
profiles.forEach( (profile) => {
  let element = `<tr><td>${profile.title}</td><td>${profile.description}</td></tr>`;
  if ( profile.url !== undefined ) {
    element = `<tr><td>${profile.title}</td><td><a href="${profile.url}" target="_blank">${profile.description}</a></td></tr>`;
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', element);
});
```

Esto funciona bien, el problema es que cuando llego a los 11 elementos del arreglo no lo ordena correctamente. Ejemplo:

Debería obtener esto:

```
Age
Digimon
Github
Hobbies
Job
MAL
Name
OS
Steam
Twitter
Type
```

Pero obtengo esto:

```
Job
OS
Github
Digimon
Name
MAL
Hobbies
Age
Steam
Twitter
Type
```

Hasta ahora he intentado meter tanto la declaración del arreglo como el sort dentro de una función que retorna una promesa, para después utilizar el `then` de esa promesa y así insertar en el HTML, pero funcionó exactamente igual. Se veía algo así:

```
let ordenar = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    let profiles = [
      {..},{..}
    ];

    profiles.sort( (a, b) => {
      return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase();
    });

    resolve(profiles);

  });
}

ordenar().then(resp => {
  resp.forEach( (profile) => {
    ....
  });
}).catch();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función sort de los arrays no espera un boolean en la comparación, si no un -1, 0 ó 1.

La [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) dice que tiene que ser así o si no especifica lo siguiente: `Si se retornan resultados inconsistentes entonces el orden de ordenamiento es indefinido.`

Tendrás que hacer la función sort con una comparación del tipo:

```
profiles.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.title > b.title) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.title < b.title) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo quería agregar que para ordenar también caracteres especiales, como los acentos y las eñes, comunes en español, podemos usar [localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare) y pasar los flags de 'es' (español) y `{sensitivity: 'base'}` que hace que `á == a` por ejémplo.

```js
let profiles = [{'title': 'Az'},{'title': 'Áb'},{'title': 'ay'},{'title': 'Ña'},{'title': 'Nz'},{'title': 'ny'}];


profiles.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title, 'es', {sensitivity: 'base'}))


console.log(profiles)
```

Algunos navegadores o motores de JavaScript pueden no aceptarlo, o tener bugs. Por ejemplo nodejs v8.11.4  lo soporta pero no lo ejecuta, osea que seguramente sea un bug de esa versión de V8.